# How to get time from QTimeedit class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtimeedit

I created a QTimeedit class in pyqt5. I want to get the time that I set in it. How to get the time from qtimeedit?

Comment: It says 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'toString'

Comment: I already corrected it: docs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeedit.html#time ----> `string_time = yout_timeEdit.time().toString()`

Comment: Do you also know how to get date time in Datetimeedit?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeedit.html#date, http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeedit.html#time, http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeedit.html#dateTime-prop